# Angular filter for highlighting word(s) inside of asterik to with bold

Tags: angularjs, markdown, angular-filters

I want to input * this is a sentence * and get < strong >this is a sentence< /strong > as an output.

I have looked at https://github.com/Hypercubed/angular-marked but this gives too many options that I don't want (like headings).

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a demo filter to convert *text* to `<strong>text</strong>` here: http://plnkr.co/edit/cQjytfvsT1Qu9ygjfEHz?p=preview

```
app.filter('asteriskToBoldFilter', function($sce){
  return function(val) {
    var matches = val.match( /\*(.*?)\*/g );
    if(matches){
      matches.forEach(function(line){
        var newline = line.replace('*', '<strong>').replace('*', '</strong>');
        val = val.replace(line, newline);
      })
    }
    return $sce.trustAsHtml(val);
  };
})
```